# Как вычесть значение из словаря при совпадении ключа в Python

Tags: python

Подскажите, пытаюсь решить задачу: есть словарь меню, где ключ название продукта, а значение - цена.

```
list1 = {'Чай': 20, 'Кофе': 30, 'Вода': 10, 'Сок':35}
```

У пользователя есть кошелек с деньгами:

```
wallet = 100
```

Далее, пользователь вводит напиток из меню и мне нужно в случае совпадения введенного напитка и ключа в словаре, вычесть стоимость из кошелька.
Например, если пользователь выбрал "Чай", то 100 - 20 = 80 (остаток). Я понимаю, как это сделать через функции, расписывая каждое значение. Но такое подойдет, если словарь небольшой, а если там много ключей и значений, то как это реализовать автоматически я не знаю.
Заранее спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем же расписывать каждое значение-то? Надо просто использовать то, что ввел пользователь, в качестве ключа:

```
list1 = {'чай': 20, 'кофе': 30, 'вода': 10, 'сок':35}
wallet = 100

while wallet > 0:
    product = input("Чего изволите купить? ")
    if product.lower() in list1.keys():
        wallet -= list1[product] # новый баланс
        if wallet < 0: # если недостаточно денег
            wallet += list1[product]
            print("Недостаточно денег.")
            print(f"{product.capitalize()} стоит {list1[product]} монет, а у вас всего {wallet}.")
            break 
    else:
        print("Такого нет в продаже.")
    print(f"У вас осталось {wallet} монет.")
```

Comment: Если уж писать код, то тогда нужно ещё проверку сделать, что данный ключ есть в словаре )

Comment: @CrazyElf это будет тема следующего вопроса ;)

Comment: Так ведь и подразумевается, что нужно сравнить, что ввел пользователь и то что есть в словаре и потом только вычесть. Извиняюсь, если как-то непонятно написал вопрос, начинаю только свой путь в Питоне))

Comment: @Stepan52 дополнил код

Comment: Спасибо большое